# How do I pg_upgrade my database on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, postgresql

I was running postgres 8.4 on arch but now have 9 installed I want to use `pg_upgrade` to upgrade but I don't know what all the options I have to use are, and all the directories that I have to point it to. I think it asks for a previous pg binary directory... but that's gone. Will it still work?

I've no important data, just play db's I just want to know how to do it. I also realize this is borderline serverfault, but I feel it has as much to do with arch's install process and paths, so I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on serverfault, because I hadn't gotten an answer here, and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/206541/how-do-i-use-pg-upgrade-on-arch-linux/206970#206970) was the answer I got, it basically contains docs links. But the most important take home, in my opinion, is that to use pg_upgrade you have to have 2 versions of postgres installed side by side, as such I filed a [bug with arch](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/21929?string=postgres&project=1&type%5B0%5D=&sev%5B0%5D=&pri%5B0%5D=&due%5B0%5D=&reported%5B0%5D=&cat%5B0%5D=&status%5B0%5D=open&percent%5B0%5D=&opened=&dev=&closed=&duedatefrom=&duedateto=&changedfrom=&changedto=&openedfrom=&openedto=&closedfrom=&closedto=) to build it into the package upgrade process

Comment: Upgrading postgresql on arch is quite annoying. I saw your question but my solution was so hacky I did not think it was worth reporting it. I don't think arch developers would automate that kind of process, but maybe better documentation or an update script on AUR would do the trick.

Comment: only problem with them not automating it is the fact that 2 pg's must be side by side... idk what they'll do with the bug.